# How to keep attr set in a loop in python

Tags: python, loops, attr

How can I keep the attribute I set in a loop out of it ?

There is my code and I'll explain my problem next :

```
students = Student.find_students()

if students:
    for student in students:
        student.address=""
        address = PersonAddress.find_address_by_person(student.person)
        student.address=address
        pprint (vars(student))        

    pprint (vars(students))
```

when I print the value of `student` the address is correctly show (and the right address, that's not the problem) but when the code print the value of the global var `students` there is no more address.

What I have to do to keep it ?

Comment: Are you getting an error, or does it just not show the expected output? Do you see `address=""`, or do you see no address at all? Does `Student` implement `__str__` or `__repr__`? What is `students`, a list? In this case, `vars(students)` should not work at all.

Comment: This does not make any sense. You want to set an attribute of one object but keep it in another object?

Comment: Tobias_k : students is a list, i was thinking that the pprint of students will show directly the adress of the student andividually, with the answer of DevShark, I see that the adresse is correctly keep. 
Goyo : it make sense, i want to add an attribute to an object wich is in a list, and i have to use one list (and not one list for students and one list for the addresses) ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The address data member will be kept, even after you exit your loop.

You print the vars of `students`, and not your individual `student`.

Try this instead of your `pprint (vars(students))` :

```
for s in students:
    pprint(vars(s))
```

You'll see your addresses correctly.

Comment: oh ok ... i was thinking it will show directly the student individually. In fact, with the "for s in students" I show again the adress. Thx :)

Comment: No problem. Feel free to accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark if it works for you.